# What is the smoothness assumption in SVMs?

Tags: machine-learning, terminology, papers, support-vector-machine

In [this research paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.5068.pdf), we have the following claim

> the smoothness assumption that underlies many kernel methods such as Support Vector Machines (SVMs) does not hold for deep neural networks trained through backpropagation

Does *smoothness* here refer to no sharp rise/fall in gradients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smoothness here is the mathematical [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness), so as you implied smoothness is ruled out by output data with sharp spikes or discontinuous jumps (and possibly the data of the gradient, the gradient's gradient, ad infinitum, depending on who defines smoothness).

By any definition a lot of activation functions are not smooth, for example RELU. This means neural networks in general are not smooth.